# Job posting appears twice

Tags: job-search, employment

In January, a job posting appeared on a company website that looked interesting. I made sure I met the requirements, created an account, uploaded my documents, answered all the questions, and sent in my application.

The job posting eventually disappeared, and I assumed that they would be contacting people for interviews. I periodically checked my profile where I can see the status of my application, as of right now, it says "None" under "Actions", I take that to mean that no one looked at my application.

I'm a little disappointed, because based on the job requirements, I exceeded them. I honestly thought I would at least be contacted for an interview.

This morning, the same job posting appeared again on the companies career page (job title, location, and responsibilities are the same, the only thing that differs is the job code).

**Questions:**

1. Why did they post the same job twice? Once in January and again in March
2. Would it be foolish to submit my application again?

Comment: Is there a phone, email or any point of contact?

Comment: @HLGEM - AH! I didn't think of that, meaning they require two people for the same position. As stated below, they probably received funding for a second employee.

Comment: @Dan - They have both :D

Comment: Give them a call if you haven't already. Don't ask why they did it but that you applied and wish to follow up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be any number of reasons why the job was posted twice from computer error to funding being delayed.  IF there was some sort of a glitch, it could also explain why you received no input.

Apply again.  Even if they did ignore your first application, this will demonstrate that you **REALLY WANT THE JOB**

I've gotten interviews myself for being persistent.  It doesn't hurt, and can only benefit you.

Answer (score 2):

> I take that to mean that no one looked at my application.

You don't know that.  All you really know is that you weren't called in for an interview.

> 1. Why did they post the same job twice? Once in January and again in March

We don't know - perhaps they lost the funding for the job, then got it back again.  Or perhaps they hired someone who didn't work out.

> 2. Would it be foolish to submit my application again?

No, it would not be foolish.  You won't get hired if you don't apply, and you don't know if they've saved your previous application or not.